# Prism OnNavigatingTo no longer fires

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

We have been using **Prism.Unity.Forms (version 7.1.0.431)** with **Xamarin.Forms** for several months with good results.  We currently tried to upgrade to **(version 7.2.0.1367)**,which introduced a major change in behavior.  It appears that the **OnNavigatingTo** event, which we use throughout out our app, no longer fires after the update.  I was able to reproduce this behavior with a simple sample app.  Is this a known bug/issue?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes. There were some breaking changes regarding Navigation in the latest Prim Release:

> After numerous user survey's and interviews it became apparent that
>   the intent of INavigatingAware had been become unclear and that users
>   were actually overwhelmingly asking for a breaking change.
>   INavigatingAware is no longer supported. For those who may be using
>   OnNavigatingTo with INavigationAware this will be most impactful as a
>   behavior change as INavigatingAware has been removed from
>   INavigationAware meaning that it will no longer be called. For those
>   who have implemented INavigatingAware directly you will see a build
>   error. The impact should be minimal by simply renaming all instances
>   of INavigatingAware to Initialize.

You can read the full release notes [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases).